# Get list of event handlers of specific event from a static class using reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Edit: .Net Framework 3.5 is used (Unity3D legacy code)

There is a static class in an external library that has a static event. Simplified to this:

```
internal static class Eventie {

    public delegate void Something();

    public static event Something OnSomething;

}
```

I need to get existing event handlers for it and call one of them from my code. Something like this:

```
List<Something> delegates = typeOf(Eventie).GetEventHandlersFor(nameof(OnSomething));
delegates.Where(...).ForEach(smth => smth.Invoke()); // pseudo code here
```

There is [a solution](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/103542/Removing-Event-Handlers-using-Reflection) that works for **non static** classes and I successfully used it for meddling with `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` event, but it takes *an instance parameter* which makes it impossible (afaik) to use with static class that I got.

Comment: The usual reflection APIs are taking null if somewhere is an optional object instance involved. Meaning you should pass null if you want to interact with the static member.

Comment: Getting NRE if I use null in `EventInfo.GetValue`

Comment: Post a minimal example pls.

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

```
// get event field by name
FieldInfo info = typeof(Eventie).GetFields(AllBindings).First(fi => fi.Name == "OnSomething");

// can be null if no event handler delegates added
var eventValue = info.GetValue(null /* static we are */) as Eventie.Something; 

// and here is it; mind the null coalescing - can be null too
Eventie.Something[] invocations = eventValue?.GetInvocationList().Cast<Eventie.Something>().ToArray();
```

To remove event handler:

```
EventInfo ei = typeof(Eventie).GetEvent(nameof(Eventie.OnSomething));
ei.RemoveEventHandler(null, invocations[i]); // where i is an index
```